# R: In a User-defined Fn, can I incorporate delayed commands, possibly with user input?

Tags: r, user-defined-functions, delayed-execution

I'm trying to create a user-defined function (lets call it `udf`) that will allow me to combine a few lines of code so it's condensed and easier to read.

Let's just take an easy example. When I use the `tiff` function (or pretty much any output function: `png`, `jpeg`,...), I have to end it with `dev.off()`, and I was wondering if I could create a function that does something along the lines of:

```
udf <- function(title)
{tiff(filename=title)
   *execute the next line of code in my R script*
   dev.off()
}
```

So I can turn 3 lines of code into 2, i.e.:

```
tiff("plot.tiff")             # >>>>>>>>>>>    udf("plot.tiff")
plot(x)                       # >>>>>>>>>>>    plot(x)
dev.off()
```

From what I've found online, one solution was putting a delay on "dev.off()" for 1 second, but that didn't seem efficient, plus I believe the function `delay` is defunct anyways.
So I believe there's three options I'm trying to explore. Either the one above, which will wait to receive the next line of code and then execute it before `dev.off()`, or:

Maybe a function with an argument that can be executed, i.e.:

```
udf <- function(title, arg)   # >>>>>>>>>>>    udf("plot.tiff", plot(x))           
{tiff(filename=title)         # >>>>>>>>>>>    That would make it one line!
   *execute(arg)*          
   dev.off()
}
```

Or possibly a way to execute a user input prompt, i.e.:

```
udf <- function(title)
{tiff(filename=title)
   n <- prompt="Enter a command: "
   *execute(n)*
   dev.off()
}
```

There might even be another option I can't think of, but nothing seems to be coming up on the web, maybe there's a key word I'm not using in my search, but any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Best,
@UpAndComing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't "capture" subsequent function calls, but you can pass a code block to a function call. For example, with something simple

```
udf <- function(title, code) {
   cat("start - ", title, "\n")
   code
   cat("end\n")
}

udf("hello", cat("ok\n"))
# start -  hello 
# ok
# end
```

which in your example would look something like

```
udf("plot.tiff", plot(x) )
```

If you have more than one expression, you can use braces.

```
udf("plot.tiff", {
  plot(x)
  plot(y)
} )
```